# Prove that this affine transformation is a translation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and $\phi:K^n \to K^n$ an affine mapping with no fixed points. Suppose that for points $P, Q \in K^n$ the lines $\phi(P)P$ and $\phi(Q)Q$ are parallel. Prove that $\phi$ is a translation.

This is what I've thought so far:
I suspect that the linear transformation of $\phi$ is the identity mapping, so that the effect of $\phi$ is simply translation.
My problem is that I'm not sure what is meant by the "the line $\phi(P)P$". Is this the affine hull of the points $\phi(P)$ and $P$? Is it the vector $P - \phi(P)$? I'm not sure how to use this in the proof.

A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: I expect $\phi(P)P$ is the affine hull (line through) the distinct points $\phi(P)$ and $P$. This is why $\phi$ has to have no fixed points.

Comment: Right, that would make sense. The affine hull of $\phi(P)$ and $P$ was defined as the smallest affine set that contains these two points. Is there a different useful characterisation of the affine hull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've got so far:

First, since $\phi$ is an affine transformation, there is a linear transformation $A$ and a vector $a \in K^n$ such that $\phi(x) = Ax + a$.

Now let $x \in K^n$ be arbitrary. The line passing through $x$ and $\phi(x)$ can be written as $ \phi(x)x = K (x - \phi(x)) + x$, that is, scalar multiples of the vector $x - \phi(x)$ translated by $x$. We know in particular that the lines $\phi(x)x$ and $\phi(a)a$ are parallel. This means that the associated linear spaces $K (x - \phi(x))$ and $K (a - \phi(a))$ are equal. Then it follows that $$ (x - \phi(x)) = (a - \phi(a))$$ $$\iff x - Ax - a = Ax$$ $$\iff Ax = \frac{1}{2} (x - a)$$ so that $$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x + a).$$

Could this be a translation? There must be something wrong with the logic because if the above is true, then $a$ would be a fixed point, which isn't allowed.

I don't know how to proceed in the proof. Can someone please share another hint?